# Creating vertical lines inside panel in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I am trying to create vertical lines inside a panel in my winform application. I am able to draw the lines but they are not what I am expecting to be. My requirements are:

1. The lines must be drawn from the middle of the panel vertically.
2. The lines must be drawn on both the sides with equal height.

The problem is when I am trying to draw the lines they are drawn from top of the panel and are upside down.

[image]

My target is to get something like:

[image]

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
public void DrawLines(System.Drawing.Graphics g, float height)
{
    Pen thePen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1.0F);            

    PointF[] points1 =
     {
        new PointF(5,5),
        new PointF(5, 50)
     };

    PointF[] points2 =
     {
        new PointF(7,5),
        new PointF(7, 60)
     };

    PointF[] points3 =
     {
        new PointF(9,5),
        new PointF(9, 55)
     };

    //Tried this as well
    //PointF[] points1 =
    // {
    //    new PointF(5,50),
    //    new PointF(5, 5)
    // };

    //PointF[] points2 =
    // {
    //    new PointF(7,60),
    //    new PointF(7, 5)
    // };

    //PointF[] points3 =
    // {
    //    new PointF(9,55),
    //    new PointF(9, 5)
    // };

    g.DrawLines(thePen, points1);
    g.DrawLines(thePen, points2);
    g.DrawLines(thePen, points3);
}
```

Right now I am calling this function on button click.

```
DrawLines(panel1.CreateGraphics(), 20.0F);
```

In real time this will be called inside a loop and line height will be passed as a parameter.

Comment: Coords in Panel (GUI Elements in general) go X: left to right, 0 is left , Y: **Top to Bottom** , 0 is top

Comment: ^^ So to draw something "from middle to whatever" you need to start at panel.height/2 and then for "up" draw to panel.height/2 - lineLength and for "down" draw to panel.Heigt/2 + lineLength.

Comment: ^^ Or you can center a line by drawing from start = (panel.Height - lineLength)/2 to end = start + lineLength. Consider that line length should respect panel measurements, too (or they will be clipped). So you may want to normalize values to percentage of height and go from there.

Comment: Can you please add it as answer so that I can accept it? I think I got what you are talking about.

Comment: Note that you can `TranslateTranform()` the world coordinates, so increment in Y will increase *upwards* instead of *downwards* -- You're never using the `height` value, so it's not exactly clear what you're doing or when these lines are drawn (what triggers a new drawing or adds to the existing) -- Don't use a Panel for drawing, use a PictureBox or a (non-System) flat Label or a double-buffered Custom Control. -- Don't use `CreateGraphics()`, use the Graphics object provided by the `Paint` event handler of your *canvas*.

Answer (score 2):

As already commented, Y coordinates are flipped when drawing on the Panel. You can test this by simply displaying mouse coordinates.

To draw the Lines you want to get the Middle of the panel and work from there. In your example you had an unused height variable, so i added funtionality to that. Here is a working example.

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1.0F);
}
private Pen _myPen;
private void DrawLines(Graphics g, int width = 0, int height = 0)
{
    // Get the middle of the panel
    int panelMiddle = panel.Height / 2;

    // Lines going up from the mittle
    g.DrawLines(_myPen,
        new PointF[]
        {
            new PointF(width + 5, height + panelMiddle -5),
            new PointF(width + 5, height + panelMiddle - 50) 
        });

    g.DrawLines(_myPen,
       new PointF[]
       {
            new PointF(width + 7, height + panelMiddle-5),
            new PointF(width + 7, height + panelMiddle - 60)
       });

    g.DrawLines(_myPen,
       new PointF[]
       {
            new PointF(width + 9, height + panelMiddle-5),
            new PointF(width + 9, height + panelMiddle - 55)
       });

    // Lines going down from the middle
    g.DrawLines(_myPen,
        new PointF[]
        {
            new PointF(width + 5, height + panelMiddle +5),
            new PointF(width + 5, height + panelMiddle + 50)
        });

    g.DrawLines(_myPen,
       new PointF[]
       {
            new PointF(width + 7, height + panelMiddle+5),
            new PointF(width + 7, height + panelMiddle + 60)
       });

    g.DrawLines(_myPen,
       new PointF[]
       {
            new PointF(width + 9, height + panelMiddle+5),
            new PointF(width + 9, height + panelMiddle + 55)
       });
}

private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawLines(e.Graphics);
    DrawLines(e.Graphics,panel.Width - 14);

}
```

Comment: That's better. The *How to `Invalidate()` the canvas* part is missing, but, well...